# Javascript - force words in text to go to newline if tehy are last in row

Tags: text-alignment

Can i force some strings in text to go to newline if they are last ones in row?

For example, i have block of text:

```
Sed ut perspiciatis unde 
omnis iste sit natus error sit 
accusantium doloremque
```

And it shoudl look like this:

```
Sed ut perspiciatis unde 
omnis iste sit natus error
sit accusantium doloremque
```

Notice that only "sit" that was last word in row was affected.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. In Html the text will fill the whole container if you don't use line breaks. It will do what you expect. If you want to do this manually, you need to measure the width of each word in your text, splitted by whitespaces. If you use fixed width font, it is easier, otherwise you need to know the width of each character.

Comment: Because i want to have newlines only for specific words, like "sit" in example. And only if specific word is last in line.

Answer (score 0):

```
sit\s*\n
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/iXbDwF59xHhZaLoS)

The following code will replace all of the "sit" words at the end of the line:

```
var newString = yourString.replace( new RegExp("sit\\s*\\n","g"), "\nsit " );
```

Comment: If you want to replace multiple words at the same time, you can use the following:
.replace( new RegExp("(sit|asd|qwe)\\s*\\n","g"), "\n$1 " )

Comment: Unfortunately it does not finds match when i use it in js code.

Comment: Do you set the line breaks in the raw text, or do you want the browser to do it automatically? This code will just work in the first case